# Create plugin in Videojs 4.0

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I have created a plugin like this for 4.0+ version

```
function examplePlugin(options) {
    this.on('play', function(e) {
    console.log('playback has started!');
    });

    vjs.NewPlayButton = vjs.Component.extend({
        init: function(player, options){
            vjs.Component.call(this, player, options);
            console.log('init New play btn');
        }
    });  

};
```

and registered the plugin like

```
vjs.plugin('examplePlugin', examplePlugin);
```

and I have included the libraries on top of html like

```
<script src="js/video.dev.js"></script>
<script src="js/exampleplugin.js"></script>
```

In lot of example i have seen that , we can initialize the plugin by the current instance of video , i want to add this plugin in all instance, that will be dynamic.

So just like a default component it has to add. Now im not getting any logs.

Is there any way to initialize it ? Not even as a plugin , i just want to add one more custom component.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are automatically added to the Player prototypes but there's no way to auto initialize them that I know of. What I think you want is to add a component to the default list of components.

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.0.4/src/js/core.js#L82

You could try something like:

`videojs.options.children.newPlayButton = {};`

(in addition to the code you had for making videojs.NewPlayButton)